# SCTP State Cookie

Tags: cookies, sctp

I know that sctp does prevents SYN/Flooding (Denial of service) by the use of state cookies every echoed cookie is stored at a session-browser buffer level.
But what does the state cookie actually contains?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RFC-4960, chapter 5.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4960#section-5.1.3) describes it in details:

> 5.1.3.  Generating State Cookie
>
> When sending an INIT ACK as a response to an INIT chunk, the sender
> of INIT ACK creates a State Cookie and sends it in the State Cookie
> parameter of the INIT ACK.  Inside this State Cookie, the sender
> should include a MAC (see [RFC2104] for an example), a timestamp on
> when the State Cookie is created, and the lifespan of the State
> Cookie, along with all the information necessary for it to establish
> the association.
>
> The following steps SHOULD be taken to generate the State Cookie:
>
> 1. Create an association TCB using information from both the
>    received INIT and the outgoing INIT ACK chunk,
> 2. In the TCB, set the creation time to the current time of day,
>    and
>    the lifespan to the protocol parameter 'Valid.Cookie.Life' (see
>    Section 15),
> 3. From the TCB, identify and collect the minimal subset of
>    information needed to re-create the TCB, and generate a MAC using
>    this subset of information and a secret key (see [RFC2104] for an
>    example of generating a MAC), and
> 4. Generate the State Cookie by combining this subset of
>    information
>    and the resultant MAC.
>
> After sending the INIT ACK with the State Cookie parameter, the
> sender SHOULD delete the TCB and any other local resource related to
> the new association, so as to prevent resource attacks.
>
> The hashing method used to generate the MAC is strictly a private
> matter for the receiver of the INIT chunk.  The use of a MAC is
> mandatory to prevent denial-of-service attacks.  The secret key
> SHOULD be random ([RFC4086] provides some information on randomness
> guidelines); it SHOULD be changed reasonably frequently, and the
> timestamp in the State Cookie MAY be used to determine which key
> should be used to verify the MAC.
>
> An implementation SHOULD make the cookie as small as possible to
> ensure interoperability.